# Trouble accessing Netflix

Tags: wine, google-chrome, netflix, pipelight

I've spent 4 hours trying to get Netflix to work on my Ubuntu. I've been to many Help pages and tried various things, including: trying to install Chrome and failing ("Failed to satisfy all dependencies [broken cache]); updating Wine; installing and updating Pipelight through Terminal.

I am currently operating on Ubuntu 12.4 LTS. Should I just update to the newest version of Ubuntu?

Thank you!

Comment: Updating would be a good thing to do regardless of problems, and who knows, it might solve the problem.

Comment: Do you use Netflix through a browser or an app?

Comment: Okay I'll update. Tried Netflix through browser and app. Installed Firefox User Agent Overrider. Says I need a newer version of Chrome or Firefox and/or Silverlight.

Comment: Update and install chromium

Comment: Also make sure you select to install Flash as well when you install chromium

Comment: "Third party sources disabled

Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool or your package manager."

Does this matter for Netflix?

Comment: Could.  You need to go into software center and in preferences you need to allow the third party sources.

Comment: Have you installed Google Chrome? not Chromium, Google Chrome. You will need it to see DRM content.

Comment: Is full chrome available @xangua

Comment: @Daniel https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/10/psa-netflix-ubuntu-now-working-box

Comment: OK then @robobenklein, I was not aware of that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First off, I recommend updating to at least 14.04 LTS, as there's no reason to install an old LTS while there's a better one.

Netflix on Linux is only supported in Chrome, not Chromium, not any other browser claiming to be Chrome either.

You should download the Ubuntu version of Chrome directly from [it's website: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html). Once installed, everything should work out of the box.

If you get any missing dependency problems while installing Chrome, attempt to install each package by `sudo apt-get install <package>`, if it can't locate the package, it may be that a required library is only available on a newer version of Ubuntu.

In such a case, I know for a fact that Netflix works on 14.04 LTS, 14.10, and 15.04 using Chrome 43.

If you get the `[broken chache]` issue when installing the package, you should issue a few commands to clean up your install environment:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That should purge all caches, install missing dependencies, then upgrade old packages in that order.

Answer (score 1):

Yes upgrade to 14.04 LTS first then install the official Chrome browser for Ubuntu from here:
https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html

After that Netflix should work like a charm

(Netflix access, without hacking, has been available to ubuntu users since late last year.)
https://insights.ubuntu.com/2014/10/10/watch-netflix-in-ubuntu-today/

Comment: Awesome, not sure which of those things worked, but Chrome and Netflix are up and running! Thanks!